# reloading a component in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-routing, reload

I've looked at a couple pages on here that I thought would have the answer and they either don't, or I'm not understanding, so here goes.

Very simply, I have an application. Within this application, I have several different "Overview" paths. One such path is for products, which end on a product information page. On some of these pages, are links to product information for other products. The trick is, that the page doesn't take parameters per se. There's an injected service that holds all the necessary data for when it's time to look up the product's information - i.e.: there are no url or param changes. Obviously a simple:

`this.router.navigate(['productInfo']);`

doesn't work. I just throw a bunch of errors since I reset the data upon which the page is built. So, I basically end up breaking the current page, and not reloading it, which would trigger it looking up the new data in the service that I just set.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposted from my comment on the other answer, I ended up finding the answer elsewhere.

I set the `this.router.navigated` to `false` and was able to navigate as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that if I got your question properly but I believe that you have one service that holds data whatever you need to display as information etc..
There is a concept of loading services at top/global level that can be used (as a shared resource) in all the components doesn't matter your path or subpath. So you can communicate or share your whole data throughout the anuglar2 application.
Further, I can assist you if you can provide more detail and better explanation (if possible your code).

Thanks

Comment: I ended up finding the answer in a different SO question finally. Basically I set the this.router.navigated to false and was able to navigate as normal.